# Installing Emmet and other packages on Atom Text Editor

Tags: emmet, atom-editor

I'm having issues installing emmet.io as a package on Atom Text Editor (Win7 x64).

Any idea of how I could do this?

I get always an error message

```
`npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/emmet
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/emmet
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/requirejs
npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/requirejs
npm ERR! not found: git
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed using git.
npm ERR! This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.`

`npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "c:\\Users\\USERNAME\\Desktop\\Atom\\resources\\app\\apm\\node_modules\\atom-package-manager\\bin\\\\node.exe" "c:\\Users\\USERNAME\\Desktop\\Atom\\resources\\app\\apm\\node_modules\\atom-package-manager\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "--globalconfig" "c:\\Users\\USERNAME\\Desktop\\Atom\\resources\\app\\apm\\node_modules\\atom-package-manager\\.apmrc" "--userconfig" "C:\\Users\\OMARSERVICE\\.atom\\.apmrc" "install" "C:\\Users\\USERNAME\\.atom\\.node-gyp\\.atom\\.apm\\emmet\\2.1.3\\package.tgz" "--target=0.11.13" "--arch=ia32" "--msvs_version=2012"
npm ERR! cwd C:\Users\USERNAME~1\AppData\Local\Temp\apm-install-dir-114726-7860-1j2mfss
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.26
npm ERR! npm -v 1.4.4
npm ERR! code ENOGIT`
```

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found a solution of how install any package on Atom.io

Instruction for Windows 7 (x32/x64)

Note: Make sure Atom.io is closed.

1. Download https://windows.github.com/
2. Run the installation as standard
3. Run Git Shell (figure #1)
4. Locate the directory via Git Shell: `cd ~/.atom/packages`
5. Run `git clone https://github.com/emmetio/emmet-atom` or whatever package you are looking forward to install (figure #2)
6. Next, got to `cd emmet-atom` (figure #3)
7. Lastly run `npm install` (figure #4)

You can follow this instructions by any package as long its GitHub  like this `https://github.com/github-user/package-name`. In short copy the url of your appropriate package.

That's it!!

Screenshots:

[image: Step 3 (figure #1)]
[image: Step 5 (figure #2)]
[image: Step 6 (figure #3)]
[image: Step 7 (figure #4)][4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9z70g.png)

Comment: You should be able to run `apm install emmet` and it should do all of these steps automatically for you.

Answer (score 0):

In your question, Atom/apm/npm is complaining about not being able to find the `git` command. It needs the `git` executable to install the package from Github.

To fix this, you need to make sure that

1. Git is installed on your machine
2. The `git` executable is on your path

Answer (score 0):

If you have GIT installed on your computer you most likely need to go to your **Control Panel\System and Security\System**  Click on **Advanced system setting** click on **Environment Variables** and under system NOT USER variables select the **Path** variable and click **edit** and add **C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;**(or where ever your git.exe file exists) to the string.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. I solved it this way: install git 2.1.3 from [repo](http://git-scm.com), then copy&paste the path of bin git into `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin` insdide of path on environment variables. After reboot your PC , open atom text edit and search in settings -> package, write `emmet`, click on button, install it and now it works, emmet is installed.